# Switching layouts page jumping (improvement to script)

Tags: jquery, page-jump

I'm using this script to switch layouts in a page:

```
$("span.switcher").click(function () {
    $("span.switcher").toggleClass("swap"); /*!*/
    $("ol.search-results").fadeOut("fast", function() {
        $(this).fadeIn("fast").toggleClass("grid");
});
```

The script works fine, the problem I have is that if the switch view is down the page, the layout changes and then the page jumps back up.

If I add 'return false' right where you see the /* ! */ in the second line the script doesn't work.

Also, as you can see, I'm using < span > instead of < a > since I was told that using other element other than < a > would stop the page from jumping.

Any idea how to fix the jumping of the page?

Thanks.

Comment: Looks like you're missing the closing curly bracket `}` for your callback to `fadeOut()`. Is that just a typo here?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As [this](http://alexcuesta.wordpress.com/2009/10/14/jquery-how-to-avoid-scrolling-when-using-fadeinfadeout-effects/) blog post mentions, the page is scrolled up because

> fadeOut sets the css property display to none.

The solution, also given in the blog, would be to use `fadeTo()` instead of `fadeOut()` and `fadeIn()`, like this:

```
$("span.switcher").click(
    function () {
        $("span.switcher").toggleClass("swap");
        $("ol.search-results").fadeTo("fast", 0,
            function () {
                $(this).fadeTo("fast", 1).toggleClass("grid");
            }
        );
    }
);
```

---

Regarding using an `a` element instead of `span`, you can do several things to prevent the default behaviour of the link (which would be to jump to the top of the page if its `href` attribute was `"#"`). How to do this and the effects of it is discussed in [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1357118/javascript-event-preventdefault-vs-return-false) SO question.

Comment: This one worked 50%. The page doesn't jump back up... all the way, it jumps back up to the middle of the page (maybe a little bit lower than the middle, but still jumps).

Any other suggestions? 

Thanks.

Comment: Too bad :/ [This](http://pastebin.com/4VWqfn7U) is the HTML/JS i used to test with. Maybe you can get something useful out of it :)

Comment: Thanks for your help Simen. Yes, that test code does actually jump back up the page as well, as I said, not all the way, just a little below the middle of the page :(.

Thanks again though, appreciate your help and your time.

Comment: Interesting, what browser are you using?

Comment: I test in all these: IE6, IE7, IE8, FF3.6.x, Chrome, Safari 3.2.x, Safari 4.x, Opera 10.x

Comment: Sorry for my such-late answer selection. I started from scratch another implementation of the switch view script  and added your fix to it and it worked perfectly. The 'fadeTo' function was the key. Thanks a lot for your help. I stayed with the use of < span > for SEO reasons since the "a href=" element should be used for actual links instead of 'triggers' since they are second to H1 tags in SEO weight. Thanks again.

Answer (score 2):

You need to reference the event in the function call and stopPropagation on it:

```
$("span.switcher").click(function (event) {

    event.stopPropagation();

    $("span.switcher").toggleClass("swap"); /*!*/
    $("ol.search-results").fadeOut("fast", function() {
        $(this).fadeIn("fast").toggleClass("grid");
    });

});
```

This stops the click from being notified to anything other than this binding.

Comment: Unfortunately your suggestion didn't work :(. It stops the switch view altogether. 

Any other ideas?

Thanks.

Comment: You might need the stopPropagation() at the end.  Otherwise, I'll think about it when I have a moment and get back to you.